# Confounding problem about iptables

Tags: iptables

Recently, I used `wget` to try to pull down some packages through port 80. It is blocked by iptable (after the service `iptables` stops, `wget` can download the packages). Could anybody help me analyze my iptable rules?

I think I've opened all the ports for local IPs (`192.168.0.0/16`, `10.0.0.0/8`), so why is it blocked?

My computer's IP is `192.168.1.168`.

If I prepare a web server at `192.168.1.170`, I can download the page from `192.168.1.170`.

```
table：filter
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/8            0.0.0.0/0           
3    ACCEPT     all  --  10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0           
4    ACCEPT     all  --  127.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0           
5    ACCEPT     all  --  169.254.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           
6    ACCEPT     all  --  172.16.0.0/12        0.0.0.0/0           
7    ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           
8    ACCEPT     all  --  224.0.0.0/4          0.0.0.0/0           
9    ACCEPT     all  --  240.0.0.0/4          0.0.0.0/0           
10   ACCEPT     all  --  144.168.60.32        0.0.0.0/0           
11   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21701 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
12   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:21701 state ESTABLISHED 
13   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:26941 state ESTABLISHED 
14   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:21713 state ESTABLISHED 
15   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:21715 state ESTABLISHED 
16   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:21714 state ESTABLISHED 
17   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED 
18   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
19   ACCEPT     tcp  --  23.105.194.21       0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8170 state ESTABLISHED 
20   ACCEPT     udp  --  114.114.114.114      0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:53 dpts:1024:65535 
21   ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 
22   ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 11 
23   ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 0 
24   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8080 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
25   ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:123 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
2    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/8           
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.0/8          
4    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.0/8         
5    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            169.254.0.0/16      
6    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.16.0.0/12       
7    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.0/16      
8    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            208.0.0.0/4         
9    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            240.0.0.0/4         
10   ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            144.168.60.32       
11   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:21701 state ESTABLISHED 
12   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21701 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
13   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:26941 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
14   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21713 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
15   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21715 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
16   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21714 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
17   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
18   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED 
19   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            23.105.194.26      tcp dpt:8170 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
20   ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            114.114.114.114     udp spts:1024:65535 dpt:53 
21   ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 
22   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8080 state ESTABLISHED 
23   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8080 state ESTABLISHED 
24   ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:123 

table：nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 to:172.17.42.1:80 

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
2    MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.3           172.17.0.3          tcp dpt:80 
3    MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.3           172.17.0.3          tcp dpt:22 
4    MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.3           172.17.0.3          tcp dpt:21 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake. Somehow, I do not know why my device name changed from eth0 to eth1. So all the rules is only valid for eth0.

@Alexis Wilke, thanks for your response!

So anyone who ask question about iptables, should paste their "iptables -L -v" instead of "iptables -L".

Comment: This is not really an answer. If Alexis' answer helped you find the solution, then this should possibly be a comment to his answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda The question is an induvidual debug problem, and this was the solution. I don't know what should be done in these cases - it is unlikely that anyone other googler would face the same problem, thus the question could be deleted. But also the big part of the site could be deleted on this reason; and it would be surreal for a Unix site to not allow induvidual system debug requests. I think the best to do if we allow it (as on the current site rules), but in this case it is an answer.

Comment: @peterh I hear (see?) what you're saying, and I agree.

Comment: Ah! Yes. With time somehow the Ethernet numbers can change. It happened several times on my computer. I have eth0 to eth4 and they changed several times.

Answer (score 1):

The chain has to be ACCEPT, this is wrong:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
```

Then you want a last rule that blocks everything else:

```
13740   717586 LOG        all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 8 level 4 prefix "[iptables] A: "
13740   717586 REJECT     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

I personally like to `LOG` before the `DROP` or `REJECT`. The difference between the two is that `REJECT` sends a reply whereas the `DROP` just stops right there. I use `DROP` for certain things and `REJECT` for others...

In most cases, the `FORWARD` is only necessary if you want a local computer on your LAN to access your Internet connection. Otherwise that one can remain `DROP`. I would not define any Output rules until the Input works.

To look at your rules, I suggest the following:

```
iptables -L -nvx | less -S
```

which will give you the counts. That allows you to see where the packets get blocked. In your case, it would appear in the `Chain INPUT` such as:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 10 packets, 1240 bytes)
```